# Read a file in WinRT class library

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-async

In a Windows Store app project I was reading a File like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/Accounts.csv");
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);

var read = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

The file `Accounts.csv` was added with build action `content`.

I have now moved the code to a separate class library. File is still added with build Action `content`.

But the uri scheme does not seem to work anymore.

I've also tried:

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("/DataModel/Accounts.csv");
var read = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

How do I access a file in a WinRT class library? Does the file library behave differently than the Store app project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access file in Windows Store class library like this.

```
var _Assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("ASSEMBLY_NAME"));
var _Stream = _Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YOUR_FILE_NAME_WITH_PATH.xml");
```

Please note in class library path members are seperated by `.` not by `\`

To get all the resource names

```
var names = _Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

The `GetManifestResourceStream` method will always returns NULL if the resource `built action` property is not set to `embedded resource`

Comment: As you state correctly your solution works in case build action is set to `embedded resource`. but I have set build action to `content`.

Comment: But `content` build action won't work, you have to use `embedded resource` if it's class library.

Comment: Is this a new limitation with WindowsRT? In .Net it was possible to add files to class libraries with `content build action` and `copy if newer`. Within the assembly you could just write a simple `var text = File.ReadAllText("TextFile1.txt")` to access the file.

Comment: +1 Great answer! The path is something like:MyClassLib.DataModel.Accounts.csv.  I use GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly to get the executing assembly.